# How can I access the MySQL command line with XAMPP for Windows?

Tags: windows, xampp, mysql

How can I access the MySQL command line with XAMPP for Windows?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Your MySQL binaries should be somewhere under your XAMPP folder. Look for a /bin folder, and you'll find the mysql.exe client around. Let's assume it is in c:\xampp\mysql\bin, then you should fireup a command prompt in this folder.

That means, fire up "cmd", and type:

```
cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql.exe -u root --password
```

If you want to use mysqldump.exe, you should also find it there.

Log into your mysql server, and start typing your commands.

Comment: That helped a lot. It turned out the exact syntax from the Windows command line was: "mysql --user=user_name --password=the_password db_name"

Comment: Also thanks for the comment about mysqldump - I was under the mistaken impression you access it from the mysql command line instead of the windows command line.

Comment: .\mysql -u root (use this in powershell ".\" means look for executable or binary in present working directory)

Comment: I was trying it in VSCode with Git Bash as my terminal. I had to use `./mysql -u root` (notice the dot and slash before mysql), else it would not see mysql.exe (yes, I had done the `cd` command already).

Answer (score 45):

On the Mac, or at least on my Mac using a default install, I accessed it at:

```
/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/bin/mysql -uroot -p
```

Comment: Yes, but did I just read the question:"How can I access the MySQL command line with XAMPP for **Windows**?"..LOL

Comment: Note for anyone as stymied by this as I initially was: if it's a new install of XAMPP, just hit return when it asks for the password, there isn't one.

Answer (score 44):

For Linux:

```
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

To use just 'mysql -u root -p' command then add '/opt/lampp/bin' to the PATH of the environment variables.

Comment: If one has left the default so that mysql dbs don't have passwords, then the following command is just slightly faster:
`/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -uroot`
Without the "-p" you'll be logged in immediately. With the "-p" there, then it will ask for a password and you need to hit enter/return to get in.

Answer (score 34):

To access the `mysql` command in Windows without manually changing directories, do this:

- Go to Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings.
- System Properties will appear.
- Click on the 'Advanced' tab.
- Click 'Environment Variables'.
- Under System Variables, locate 'Path' and click Edit.
- Append the path to your MySQL installation to the end of the exisiting 'Variable value'. Example:

  ```
  %systemDrive%\xampp\mysql\bin\
  ```

  or, if you prefer

  ```
  c:\xampp\mysql\bin\
  ```
- Finally, open a new command prompt to make this change take effect.

*Note that [MySQL's documentation on Setting Environment Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/setting-environment-variables.html) has little to say about handling this in Windows.*

Comment: That works. I just needed to skip the last back slash: c:\xampp\mysql\bin

Answer (score 30):

1. Open the XAMPP control panel.
2. Click `Shell`.
3. Type `mysql --user=your_user_name --password=your_password`.

Comment: I found this solution is perfect for Xampp.

Answer (score 15):

You can  access the MySQL command line with XAMPP for Windows

[image]

1. click XAMPP icon to launch its cPanel
2. click on Shell button
3. Type this `mysql -h localhost -u root` and click enter

**You should see all the command lines and what they do**

```
Setting environment for using XAMPP for Windows.
Your PC c:\xampp

# mysql -h localhost - root

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.19-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
C:\WINDOWS\my.ini C:\WINDOWS\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\xampp\mysql\my.ini C:\xampp\mysql\my.cnf C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.cnf
The following groups are read: mysql client client-server client-mariadb
The following options may be given as the first argument:
--print-defaults        Print the program argument list and exit.
--no-defaults           Don't read default options from any option file.
--defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the given file #.
--defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the global files are read.

  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
  --abort-source-on-error
Abort 'source filename' operations in case of errors
  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use
                      'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup
                      and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with
                      --disable-auto-rehash.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)
  -A, --no-auto-rehash
                      No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get
                      table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of
                      mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.
  --auto-vertical-output
                      Automatically switch to vertical output mode if the
                      result is wider than the terminal width.
  -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable interactive behavior.
                      (Enables --silent.)
  --character-sets-dir=name
                      Directory for character set files.
  --column-type-info  Display column type information.
  -c, --comments      Preserve comments. Send comments to the server. The
                      default is --skip-comments (discard comments), enable
                      with --comments.
  -C, --compress      Use compression in server/client protocol.
  -#, --debug[=#]     This is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.
  --debug-check       Check memory and open file usage at exit.
  -T, --debug-info    Print some debug info at exit.
  -D, --database=name Database to use.
  --default-character-set=name
                      Set the default character set.
  --delimiter=name    Delimiter to be used.
  -e, --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history
                      file.)
  -E, --vertical      Print the output of a query (rows) vertically.
  -f, --force         Continue even if we get an SQL error. Sets
                      abort-source-on-error to 0
  -G, --named-commands
                      Enable named commands. Named commands mean this program's
                      internal commands; see mysql> help . When enabled, the
                      named commands can be used from any line of the query,
                      otherwise only from the first line, before an enter.
                      Disable with --disable-named-commands. This option is
                      disabled by default.
  -i, --ignore-spaces Ignore space after function names.
  --init-command=name SQL Command to execute when connecting to MySQL server.
                      Will automatically be re-executed when reconnecting.
  --local-infile      Enable/disable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.
  -b, --no-beep       Turn off beep on error.
  -h, --host=name     Connect to host.
  -H, --html          Produce HTML output.
  -X, --xml           Produce XML output.
  --line-numbers      Write line numbers for errors.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-line-numbers to disable.)
  -L, --skip-line-numbers
                      Don't write line number for errors.
  -n, --unbuffered    Flush buffer after each query.
  --column-names      Write column names in results.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-column-names to disable.)
  -N, --skip-column-names
                      Don't write column names in results.
  --sigint-ignore     Ignore SIGINT (CTRL-C).
  -o, --one-database  Ignore statements except those that occur while the
                      default database is the one named at the command line.
  -p, --password[=name]
                      Password to use when connecting to server. If password is
                      not given it's asked from the tty.
  -W, --pipe          Use named pipes to connect to server.
  -P, --port=#        Port number to use for connection or 0 for default to, in
                      order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,
                      /etc/services, built-in default (3306).
  --progress-reports  Get progress reports for long running commands (like
                      ALTER TABLE)
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-progress-reports to disable.)
  --prompt=name       Set the mysql prompt to this value.
  --protocol=name     The protocol to use for connection (tcp, socket, pipe,
                      memory).
  -q, --quick         Don't cache result, print it row by row. This may slow
                      down the server if the output is suspended. Doesn't use
                      history file.
  -r, --raw           Write fields without conversion. Used with --batch.
  --reconnect         Reconnect if the connection is lost. Disable with
                      --disable-reconnect. This option is enabled by default.
                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-reconnect to disable.)
  -s, --silent        Be more silent. Print results with a tab as separator,
                      each row on new line.
  --shared-memory-base-name=name
                      Base name of shared memory.
  -S, --socket=name   The socket file to use for connection.
  --ssl               Enable SSL for connection (automatically enabled with
                      other flags).
  --ssl-ca=name       CA file in PEM format (check OpenSSL docs, implies
                      --ssl).
  --ssl-capath=name   CA directory (check OpenSSL docs, implies --ssl).
  --ssl-cert=name     X509 cert in PEM format (implies --ssl).
  --ssl-cipher=name   SSL cipher to use (implies --ssl).
  --ssl-key=name      X509 key in PEM format (implies --ssl).
  --ssl-crl=name      Certificate revocation list (implies --ssl).
  --ssl-crlpath=name  Certificate revocation list path (implies --ssl).
  --ssl-verify-server-cert
                      Verify server's "Common Name" in its cert against
                      hostname used when connecting. This option is disabled by
                      default.
  -t, --table         Output in table format.
  --tee=name          Append everything into outfile. See interactive help (\h)
                      also. Does not work in batch mode. Disable with
                      --disable-tee. This option is disabled by default.
  -u, --user=name     User for login if not current user.
  -U, --safe-updates  Only allow UPDATE and DELETE that uses keys.
  -U, --i-am-a-dummy  Synonym for option --safe-updates, -U.
  -v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).
  -V, --version       Output version information and exit.
  -w, --wait          Wait and retry if connection is down.
  --connect-timeout=# Number of seconds before connection timeout.
  --max-allowed-packet=#
                      The maximum packet length to send to or receive from
                      server.
  --net-buffer-length=#
                      The buffer size for TCP/IP and socket communication.
  --select-limit=#    Automatic limit for SELECT when using --safe-updates.
  --max-join-size=#   Automatic limit for rows in a join when using
                      --safe-updates.
  --secure-auth       Refuse client connecting to server if it uses old
                      (pre-4.1.1) protocol.
  --server-arg=name   Send embedded server this as a parameter.
  --show-warnings     Show warnings after every statement.
  --plugin-dir=name   Directory for client-side plugins.
  --default-auth=name Default authentication client-side plugin to use.
  --binary-mode       By default, ASCII '\0' is disallowed and '\r\n' is
                      translated to '\n'. This switch turns off both features,
                      and also turns off parsing of all clientcommands except
                      \C and DELIMITER, in non-interactive mode (for input
                      piped to mysql or loaded using the 'source' command).
                      This is necessary when processing output from mysqlbinlog
                      that may contain blobs.

Variables (--variable-name=value)
and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
--------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
abort-source-on-error             FALSE
auto-rehash                       FALSE
auto-vertical-output              FALSE
character-sets-dir                (No default value)
column-type-info                  FALSE
comments                          FALSE
compress                          FALSE
debug-check                       FALSE
debug-info                        FALSE
database                          (No default value)
default-character-set             auto
delimiter                         ;
vertical                          FALSE
force                             FALSE
named-commands                    FALSE
ignore-spaces                     FALSE
init-command                      (No default value)
local-infile                      FALSE
no-beep                           FALSE
host                              localhost
html                              FALSE
xml                               FALSE
line-numbers                      TRUE
unbuffered                        FALSE
column-names                      TRUE
sigint-ignore                     FALSE
port                              3306
progress-reports                  TRUE
prompt                            \N [\d]>
quick                             FALSE
raw                               FALSE
reconnect                         TRUE
shared-memory-base-name           (No default value)
socket                            C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock
ssl                               FALSE
ssl-ca                            (No default value)
ssl-capath                        (No default value)
ssl-cert                          (No default value)
ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
ssl-key                           (No default value)
ssl-crl                           (No default value)
ssl-crlpath                       (No default value)
ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE
table                             FALSE
user                              (No default value)
safe-updates                      FALSE
i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE
connect-timeout                   0
max-allowed-packet                16777216
net-buffer-length                 16384
select-limit                      1000
max-join-size                     1000000
secure-auth                       FALSE
show-warnings                     FALSE
plugin-dir                        (No default value)
default-auth                      (No default value)
binary-mode                       FALSE
```

Comment: have you try access the control panel in save mode? I am not able to do that!

Comment: @Adi Prasetyo The question was How can I access the MySQL command line with XAMPP for Windows? It never include SAVE MODE so you can reconstruct your question by how can I How can I access the MySQL command line IN SAVE MODE with XAMPP for Windows?

Answer (score 8):

Ajay,

The reason that you can't see the other tables is that you need to log in as 'root' in order to see them

```
mysql -h localhost -u root
```

Answer (score 6):

In terminal:

```
cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin

mysql -h 127.0.0.1 --port=3306 -u root --password
```

Hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> if the password is an empty string. Now you are in.
You can list all available databases, and select one using the fallowing:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
USE database_name_here;

SHOW TABLES;
DESC table_name_here;
SELECT * FROM table_name_here;
```

Remember about the "`;`" at the end of each SQL statement.

Windows cmd terminal is not very nice and does not support <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> (copy, paste) shortcuts. If you plan to work a lot in terminal, consider installing an alternative terminal cmd line, I use **cmder** terminal - [Download Page](http://cmder.net/)

Answer (score 4):

Go to `/xampp/mysql/bin`
and find for `mysql. exe`

open `cmd`, change the directory to mysq 
after write in `cmd`

`mysql -h localhost -u root`

Answer (score 3):

**Xampp control panel v2.3.1**
I got errors while using -h localhost

## mysql -h localhost -u root

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10060)
```

So, if you installed xampp as is and did not customize any documentroot, serverroot, etc. then the following works :-

> start both the services on the xampp control panel
>   click shell 
>   enter: # mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root

that works just fine.
Below is the logtrail:-

```
# mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.6.21 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Answer (score 3):

To access MySQL in Windows you need to install the XAMPP.

- Open the XAMPP Control Panel and start MySQL.
- Now go to the command prompt and open

  ```
  C:\>cd xampp
  C:\xampp>cd MySQL 
  C:\xampp\mysql>cd bin 
  C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -h localhost -u root
  ```

Your database is now ready to be executed.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Fistly,  thats what i have :

1. win 10
2. `xampp`
3. git bash

and i have done this to fix my problem :

1. go to search box(PC)
2. tape this `environnement variable`
3. go to 'path' click 'edit'
4. add this `"%systemDrive%\xampp\mysql\bin\" C:\xampp\mysql\bin\`
5. click ok
6. go to ***Git Bash*** and right click it and open it and ***run as administrator***
7. right this on your ***Git Bash*** `winpty mysql -u root` if your password is empty 
   or `winpty mysql -u root -p` if you do have a password

Answer (score 2):

[run xampp shell to solve connect to root using pw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFzbh.jpg)

`mysql -h localhost -u root -p`  and enter root pw

Answer (score 2):

To access SQL via the command line we simply navigate to the xampp folder. 
the folder is usually on the c:\ drive.

1. type: cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin then press enter.
2. type: `in mysql -u root -p`  then press enter.
3. in the new line enter the password of the database.
4. type: show databases; to see all the databases that you have access to.
5. once you know what database you want to use type (ex. cms_database), type `use cms_data` or any other db_name, it should say Database changed

// Bonus Note
you shouldn't use the root user when working with databases. you would want to create a separate account (ex. cms_user) with special privileges to limit errors.

to do that type:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES IN cms_database.*
TO 'cms_user'@'localhost' 
IDENTITIED BY 'yourpassword'
```

double check by using the command:

```
SHOW GRANT FOR 'cms_user'@localhost;
```

if you already have the name of the user and the specific database you wish to use, change step 2 to this.

```
mysql -u cms_user -p cms_database
```

Answer (score 1):

For windows

```
cd\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql -u root -p
```

Just a simple commands for linux to open mysql :

```
sudo /opt/lampp/bin/mysql
```

Answer (score 1):

to enter MySQL's command-line interface, I find this:

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysql -u root
```

Answer (score 0):

for linux users who are getting

**Command 'mysql' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install mysql-client-core-8.0     # version 8.0.30-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, or
sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.3  # version 1:10.3.34-0ubuntu0.20.04.1**

but have  xampp installed

you can just add `/opt/lampp/bin`  to your bashrc file and run mysql