# how to start xampp in windows safe mode

Tags: php, mysql, database, backup, safe-mode

i can't startup my windows (maybe virus) and i can't start `xampp` on it

i can just startup using `safe mode`

how can i start xampp in `safe mode`?

**i need my databases backup**

how can i backup my databases in `safe mode`?

i search in google but i couldn't find any thing

when i start xampp in safe mode i see this error

```
ERROR: Apache Service not started [-1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MySQL can start : follow this post to connect to mysql in console mode :
http://ja.meswilson.com/blog/2007/04/07/access-mysql-command-line-in-xampp/ 
And then backup it

**Edit :** Other link : [How can I access the MySQL command line with XAMPP for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698914/how-can-i-access-the-mysql-command-line-with-xampp-for-windows)

Comment: can you give me full database backup command line code?

Comment: Here is a link for a complete backup in command line : http://webcheatsheet.com/SQL/mysql_backup_restore.php