# XAMPP MYSQL NOT WORKING

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a problem with mysql on xampp.

cd c:/xampp/mysql/bin
mysql.exe
How to log in to my database ? 
http://wrzucacz.pl/download/5511422226146

Comment: Post it as an image not as a download.

Comment: Check this link in case it helps you with your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698914/how-can-i-access-the-mysql-command-line-with-xampp-for-windows

Comment: i have problem because when i wrote something i have on screen only -> ?

Answer (score 0):

Start MySQL from xampp control panel

```
cd c:\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql.exe -u root --password
```

you will be prompted to insert your password

A similar question though has been posted before [How can I access the MySQL command line with XAMPP for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698914/how-can-i-access-the-mysql-command-line-with-xampp-for-windows)

Comment: Yes but 2 problem. When i write to cmd after log in mysqladmin -u root create database69 i got only "->"

Comment: Remember to finish each line with ;

Comment: to use a certain database type ->\u "database_name"

Comment: once you have selected the database you want to use, type your command, e.g. select * from tablename; Don't forget to finish each line with ; as @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo wrote. In case you want to change the delimiter from ; to something else type ->\d new_delimiter_symbol_of_your_choise