# XAMPP MySQL can't start

Tags: mysql, xampp

I installed xampp but mysql can't start. I have read several threads related to it, but answers there don't work for me. It keeps halting when I tried to start mysql after changing the port or even after stopping process of another mysql server. even after trying to reboot the OS and install xampp as administrator. please help. This is the error that I got:

```
13:10:04  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
13:10:17  [mysql]   Problem detected!
13:10:17  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by "C:\AppServ\mysql\bin\mysqld-nt.exe MySQL"!
13:10:17  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
13:10:17  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
13:10:17  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
13:10:17  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL service...
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Please share your errors so we can help you to get out from this issue.

Comment: put screenshot of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had faced several issues and I can relate to this question, as its not always clear how to get mysql working on xampp; especially if u r new to a xampp environment.

Try this thread.

[How can I access the MySQL command line with XAMPP for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698914/how-can-i-access-the-mysql-command-line-with-xampp-for-windows/40212476#40212476)

It should get you started.

Comment: thanks, I can use cmd to open the mysql command line directly