# Is it possible to insert a sql code with batch file in xampp

Tags: sql, batch-file, sql-insert

I wrote a batch script that it creates a sql file for my database.

It will automatically write `id` and `image file direction` and `idproduct` but I don't know how to insert `mysql` code with using batch file to `xampp` `phpmyadmin`

Comment: You should be able to use the mysql command line tool. `mysql -u username -p password database_name < c:\full\path\to\file.sql`

Comment: `mysql` is the database. `phpmyadmin` is a web-based client for the database. `apache` is a web server. `php` is a server side scripting language. `xampp` bundles all of these together into one install/UI. You have a `sql` file that you want to connect to your `mysql` db and run against it. This has nothing to do with phpmyadmin, or xampp.  You can use the `mysql.exe` to do command line operations (batch file) against your `mysql` database [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698914/how-can-i-access-the-mysql-command-line-with-xampp-for-windows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import an SQL file using the command line in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-to-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the MySQL.exe tool in your batch:

```
mysql -u username -p password database_name < "c:\path\to\SqLfile.sql"
```