# How do I log into MySQL through XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am trying to connect to MySQL by using XAMPP command line. But I can't find the solution on the internet.

I haven't set up anything in MYSQL nor XAMPP, so the username should be 'root' while the password shouldn't exist at all.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698914/how-can-i-access-the-mysql-command-line-with-xampp-for-windows help? "I can't find the solution" isn't very helpful, can you explain what you have tried so far? Is there a specific reason you want to do this via the XAMPP CLI instead of any other method?

Comment: Yes, this method does work, but I wanted to access it via the built-in command line of XAMPP since it's much more convenient. But... I guess I'll just go along with that method.

Comment: In the future, adding information to your question like "I am able to access it via the normal command line, but for reasons x, y, and z I'd like to be able to use the XAMPP CLI" would be helpful.